# SDK Manager Failed while installing Support Library

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am using Android 4.0 and above . I need to install support libraries for one of the old project which I want to run . But it gives me an error while installing from Eclipse.Why is it and how can I solve it ? I have disabled my Antivirus , closed all the programs and windows except Eclipse and tried but still the error prevails.

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download it from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). Make sure you use the latest Version(Revision 10). Add this to your `libs` folder and include it in your java build path.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the result of a permissions error because your files are located in C:/Program Files....  Try right-clicking on the eclipse icon and choose "Run as administrator" from the context menu.